# How do I constrain my React list component to have only list items of type ItemOne or ItemTwo using Typescript generics

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, generics

In my React Typescript app I have a `<List />` component which should be *constrained* to 2 *types* of items (objects) in the list array:

```
export type ItemOne = {
  type: string;
  id: string;
  title: string;
  label: string;
  url: string;
  lead?: string;
  image: Image | null;
}
```

and:

```
export type ItemTwo = {
  title: string;
  label: string;
  duration?: string;
  uuid: string;
  url: string;
  type: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}
```

You can see type `ItemOne`  and `ItemTwo`  are distinguished by some fields like `id` and `uuid` for example.

I want to use [Typescript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) for this.

```
type Props<T> = {
 items: T[];
};

const MyList = <T extends {}>({ items }: Props<T>) => {

  const isItemTypeOne = item.type === 'Type One';

  return (
     <ul css={styles.list}>
          {items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <MyListItem
                key={isItemTypeOne ? item.uuid : item.id}
                title={item.title}
              />
            );
          })}
     </ul>
    )
  };

export default MyList;
```

How do I constrain this component to have only list items of type `ItemOne` or `ItemTwo` using generics?

Comment: In your example, you have the same type (string), so TypeScript cannot distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

```
  function isItemOne(
    value: MyListItemOne | MyListItemTwo,
  ): value is MyListItemOne {
    return !!(value as MyListItemOne).id;
  }

  type Props<
    T extends MyListItemOne | MyListItemTwo = MyListItemOne | MyListItemTwo,
  > = {
    items: T[];
  };

  function MyList({ items }: Props) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Fragment key={isItemOne(item) ? item.id : item.uuid}>
              {/*  */}
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```